# Sys.InvalideOperationsExcetion

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When I click on "Site Actions" and choose the option to "Edit Page" I get the following error message.

Sys.InvalideOperationsExcetion: Could not find UpdatedPanel with ID 'ctl00_panelZone'. If it si being updated  dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel

How do I correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, someone was trying to update the page, and cancelled it before it was finished. Either way, the Edit Page function does not recognize the Unique ID for the UpdatePanel.

> The easiest way to fix this is to go into SharePoint Designer, open the site, and check/view the history for that page. Simply restore to a previous version and that should fix it.

Or Second ways for `Edit your Page` using append a `?ToolPaneView=2` to the end of your url for the page you want to edit.

i.e : if your page was http://contoso.com/Pages/default.aspx append the ?ToolPaneView=2 to the end so it would be http://contoso.com/Pages/default.aspx?ToolPaneView=2.  This is another way to get to the edit page.

Hops its helps!!